# How to efficiently make multiple variables available for use in beforeEach in jasmine

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine

As I understand it, in order for the variables assigned to within a jasmine beforeEach to be accessible by the specs it applies to, the variables have to be declared in the containing block. I'm trying to find the least verbose way of doing this using coffeescript and came up with:

```
[var1, var2, var3, ..., varn] = [undefined]
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could drop the `undefined` I suppose:

```
[var1, var2, var3, ..., varn] = []
```

I can't think of anything else. And a better question to ask is why you need so many global-ish variables in the first place: if you need so many variables that explicitly defining them is onerous then maybe you have too many variables.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I'd tried [] and it didn't work, but clearly it does.

In fact, I don't have that many variables, but being forced to declare them outside of the beforeEach seems like a distraction to the reader, so I want to minimize the visual impact.